# Ark's Scutinphora

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, anatomy, insectoid

[image]

> Scutinphora puteus is a fast, flying insect that comes in two varieties, visually distinct only in the red or green markings on its exoskeleton. Biologically and behaviorally, the are practically the same. The only real difference between the two is the resource they gather in the expandable sacks on their backs. Scutinphora with green markings gather water, and Scutinphora with red markings gather oil. This unique ability makes Scutinphora a target for both the desert's natural predators and human survivors. Finding a green Scutinphora at the right time could prove to be life-saving, and survivors can use the oil produced by red Scutinphora for a wide variety of purposes.

How does this Giant bug or anything similar evolve and why? and how would humans and other creatures gather their water/oil  without killing them?

Comment: You're asking a lot of different questions. We have a policy of one question per post on this site.

Comment: Also, look at existing questions explaining giant bugs!

Comment: I can answer all those questions at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scutinphora reproduces by laying hundreds of waxy eggs at a time. The eggs must be kept damp to survive. The insect lives in a rocky desert where the eggs are likely to dry out in the Sun and die, and there is no place to bury them either. To solve this problem it carries the eggs with it until they hatch. They are carried in a 'sack' which is kept full of water from the insect's metabolism. The sack evolved to detach once the eggs start hatching. That's why it can be removed without killing the insect; though it will kill the eggs.

The main thing that keeps bugs small is the weight of the exoskeleton and their method of respiration (spiracles). Even the largest beetles are adept at moving large objects.

[image]

So Scutinphora can get as big as any insect. The biggest insect is the Goliath beetle which can weigh over 100 grams!